# Quick javascript split question

Tags: javascript

Just a quick question regarding the split function

How can I split my string at every 2nd space?

```
myArray = 'This is a sample sentence that I am using'
myArray = myString.split(" ");
```

I would like to create a array like this

```
This is a < 2 spaces
sample sentence that < 2 spaces
that I am  < 2 spaces
```

and if the last word is not a space how would I handle this...?

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myString = 'This is a sample sentence that I am using';
myArray = myString.match(/[^ ]+( +[^ ]+){0,2}/g);
alert(myArray);
```

Comment: Ah this is much better. (And I think `(?:...)` should be used instead of `(...)` in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

Not a beautiful solution. Assumes the `\1` character isn't used.

```
array = 'This is a sample sentence that I am using';
array = array.replace(/(\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+)\s+/g, "$1\1").split("\1");
// If you want multiple whitespaces not merging together
//   array = array.replace(/(\S*\s\S*\s\S*)\s/g, "$1\1").split("\1");
// If you only want to match the space character (0x20)
//   array = array.replace(/([^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+) +/g, "$1\1").split("\1");
alert(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Split it every space, and then concatenate every other element:

```
function splitOnEvery(str, splt, count){
  var arr = str.split(splt);
  var ret = [];
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=count){
    var tmp = "";
    for(var j=i; j<i+count; j++){
      tmp += arr[j];
    }
    ret.push(tmp);
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Havent tested the code, but should work

Comment: You can replace the loop body with a simple: `ret.push(arr.slice(i, i+count).join(splt));`.